# Data mine Excel files stored in shared drive using Synapse - is this possible?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Pretty new to Azure in general so not sure which direction to start in. We are looking to mine Excel files from a shared drive storage and I'm wondering if this is possible to do using Synapse.

My manager mentions to look into using ASA but I am not seeing an option to use local Excel files as a data source - is this actually possible to do using Synapse? If not, can someone link me to some resources for me to start with?

He mentioned to use Data Factory as well but that requires us to have a Fabric sub and a Gen2 workspace (which IT did not approve) so I'm not sure if there's actually a way to do it without the required sub tiers.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are inside a company network (on-premise) and behind a firewall, you need to install a Self-hosted integration runtime to access them. This is true in Synapse pipelines and in Azure Data Factory (ADF).

A self-hosted integration runtime is an agent you install on a server inside your network, that can access your on-premise servers or file shares, and on the other side connect to Synapse or ADF.

Link to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory

If you are able to move these Excel files outside your internal Network and into an Azure Storage Account, you may skip the installation of Self-hosted integration runtime and access the files directly (with Synapse\ADF).

Comment: I was able to set up a self-hosted IR on my PC however I am getting stuck when trying to point to a local folder (for testing), I kept getting error 2385 ("Access to folder is not allowed.")

Comment: When setting a linked service to a local folder you need to specify a username and password. Check that that user has permission to the folder.